# how can I do self-reference with ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, self-reference

I want to self-referentiate a model in a RoR app but, I don't know exactly how. I want to save a linked list where the next node has the id of the previous one. how can I do this rails way? It is a one-to-one relation.

Comment: I think you start by searching StackOverflow for "[ruby-on-rails] self referential association": http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby-on-rails%5D%20self%20referential%20association - Duplicate? :-)

Comment: actually I searched this, but they do not solve my problem.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The easiest way:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'MyModel'
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'MyModel', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
end
```

Comment: I'm using rails 3 and I need only one reference not many, has_one works? If yes, i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Perfect answer!!

Answer (score 30):

rails 5

add column xxx_id in users table:

in migration file:

```
add_reference :users, :xxx, index: true
```

and add code in User model

```
has_many :users, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'xxx_id'
belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'xxx_id'
```

If you don't have a manager for every user, you need to add optional: true.

'foreign_key' is not necessary. By default this is guessed to be the name of this class in lower-case and “_id” suffixed.

if foreign_key is user_id, user don't have manager necessary.
the result is:

```
has_many :users, class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User', optional: true
```

They are called [self-joins](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins)

Answer (score 3):

I've spent some time trying to make it work using Rails 3.2.14

The documentation's suggestion for [self-joining associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) hasn't worked for `belongs_to` associations. Adding a foreign key fixed the issue.

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invitees, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :invited_by
  belongs_to :host, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :invited_by
end
```