# How to pass in parent ID into nested attribute when parent model hasn't been created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, activerecord, database-design

I have a schoolwork platform that allow:
- users to create a homework assignment (`Work`) or quiz (`Work` that has `Questions`)
- users to submit assignments (`Submission`)

A given assignment or `work`, it can have many `submissions`. A `work` may also have many `questions`. A `question` can have many `answers`, either canonical `answers` (set by the teacher) or non-canonical `answers` (submitted by students).

When a student submits an assignment (creates a `Submission` for a given `Work`), they should see the questions relating to the work and be able to create non-canonical `answers`. A student should not be able to change any attributes of a `question`.

**Problem**: I'm thinking of using a nested form to model the above behavior, but am having some trouble populating the correct fields. I need to be able to relate an answer back to the submission it came from. However, at the moment I submit the form and call `Submission.new` / `Submission.create`, the submission doesn't have an ID yet and so I cannot populate the `answers_attribute` with the `submission_id`.

**Question**:

1. How can I fix the nested form to correctly populate `submission_id` for the answer?
2. Is there another way I can go about this to accomplish the same thing?
3. Is there a simpler way to design the relationships than what I have now?

#### Code

```
class Work < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :submissions
  has_many :questions # Allow for quizzes
  has_many :answers, through: :questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  validates :name, presence: true, allow_nil: false


end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: works
#
#  id               :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  description      :text
#  due_date         :datetime
#  grades_published :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  name             :string
#  points           :float            default(1.0)
#  published        :boolean
#  submittable      :boolean          default(TRUE)
#  url              :string
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#  category_id      :integer
#  course_id        :integer
#
```

```
class Submission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :work
  belongs_to :enrollment
  has_one :grade
  has_many :questions, through: :works
  has_many :answers, through: :questions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  validates_uniqueness_of :work_id, scope: :enrollment_id, message: " has already been submitted"

end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: submissions
#
#  id            :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  enrollment_id :integer
#  work_id       :integer
#  title         :string
#  content       :text
#  created_at    :datetime         not null
#  updated_at    :datetime         not null
#
```

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :work
  has_many :answers, inverse_of: :question
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  validates :value, presence: true, allow_nil: false
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: questions
#
#  id         :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  value      :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  work_id    :bigint(8)
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_questions_on_work_id  (work_id)
#
```

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question, inverse_of: :answers
  # belongs_to :work, through: :questions
  # belongs_to :submission, through: :works

  validates :question_id, :presence => true
  validates :value, presence: true, allow_nil: false
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: answers
#
#  id            :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  is_canon      :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  is_correct    :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  value         :string
#  created_at    :datetime         not null
#  updated_at    :datetime         not null
#  question_id   :bigint(8)
#  submission_id :bigint(8)
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_answers_on_question_id    (question_id)
#  index_answers_on_submission_id  (submission_id)
#
# Foreign Keys
#
#  fk_rails_...  (question_id => questions.id)
#  fk_rails_...  (submission_id => submissions.id)
#
```

Help is very much appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: You know your requirements better than anyone...but I'm having trouble differentiating a `Work` from a `Submission`. I'd say get rid of one or the other, which will simplify your models. Maybe a submission is more of an action taken on a `Work` object

Comment: @izy May i know what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm currently trying out Mark's suggestion and removing `Submission` and instead adding a column so that I know if the `Work` is created by a teacher or created by a student. I'm thinking of making [`Work` a self referential model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097288/how-can-i-do-self-reference-with-ruby-on-rails)


I've also tried a nested form using the Cocoon gem. `Submission` accepted attributes for `answers` and `questions`. `Work` also accepted attributes for questions. `Question` accepts attributes for `answers`

Comment: @izy Question is not clear, can you show the form by which you want to pass parent_id, that may be helpful to figure out.